# Graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges incorrect when TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit is enabled

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, graphics

I have an issue in that when I measure the width of a string using the Graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges method the result doesn't match what is displayed.

I have found that this is due to TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit.  When this is set the text is drawn wider. If it is not set the draw text matches the measurement.  I require this enabled as it ensures fonts are drawn with the highest of quality.

I need a fast method to evaluate the width of a string.  Is the only option remaining to actually draw the string on an image an check pixels for colour?

Is this a bug with the MeasureCharacterRanges method or am I doing something wrong?

NB. The issue seems to be particularly bad with this font.  Other fonts, other styles of Arial and other sizes of Arial seem to be much more accurate.  I have written a tool to enumerate all fonts/sizes and this is by far the largest discrepancy.

The below code gets the measurement, draws the text and the bounding box for the measurement.

```
    Dim g As Graphics = Nothing
    Dim text As String = "MSCI EMU Net"
    Dim font As Font = New Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Regular)
    Dim wordwrapwidth As Single = Single.MaxValue

    g = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero)
    g.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel
    g.TextContrast = 2
    g.TextRenderingHint = Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit

    Dim ranges As System.Drawing.CharacterRange() = {New System.Drawing.CharacterRange(0, text.Length)}
    Dim regions As System.Drawing.Region() = New System.Drawing.Region(0) {}

    Dim STRFormat As StringFormat = StringFormat.GenericTypographic.Clone
    STRFormat.SetTabStops(0, New Single() {72})
    STRFormat.SetMeasurableCharacterRanges(ranges)

    regions = g.MeasureCharacterRanges(text, font, New System.Drawing.RectangleF(0, 0, wordwrapwidth, Single.MaxValue), STRFormat)

    Dim tempRectF As RectangleF = regions(0).GetBounds(g)


    Dim textImage As New Bitmap(500, 100)
    Dim textImageGraphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(textImage)
    textImageGraphics.TextContrast = 2
    textImageGraphics.TextRenderingHint = Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit
    textImageGraphics.Clear(Color.White)
    textImageGraphics.DrawString(text, font, Brushes.Black, New Point(0, 0))
    textImageGraphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, Rectangle.Round(tempRectF))
    PictureBox1.Image = textImage
```

Any questions or issues please let me know.

Comment: Further testing shows this is only an issue on Server 2003/2008.  On Windows 7/8.1 it evaluates correctly.  I've compared versions of Arial and System.Drawing and haven't been able to determine why.

Comment: Use `Dim text As String = "Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii"` to see the core problem with GDI+ text rendering.

Comment: Eeek. Odd spacing much! Can you advise if this is related to my case?

Comment: Interestingly "Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii" is OK printed.  Its only an issue on screen.

Comment: I have found a solution. Details and more questions tomorrow.

Comment: What's the relevance of the "is OK printed" comment?  Are you actually sending the bitmap to a printer?

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you what happens internally in GDI+, but I can provide some clarification anyway.

Basically, if you expect a string to draw exactly with the same width as measured, you need to draw it on the same surface and with the same options.

In the original code, [`Graphics.FromHwnd`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Graphics.cs#f79ca9f14bf8f9e6) is used for *measurement* and internally uses `GdipCreateFromHWND` to create a drawing surface. [`Graphics.FromImage`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Graphics.cs#f79ca9f14bf8f9e6) instead, used for *drawing* here, uses `GdipGetImageGraphicsContext` internally. Even though the .NET properties on the `Graphics` object look the same, there may still be internal differences in regard to the internal GDI+ drawing surface.

So to simplify your solution, it would actually suffice to use

```
Dim Im As New Bitmap(500, 100)
g = Graphics.FromImage(Im)
```

Works fine on my Server 2008 system and Win7, and looks like this:

[image: Result with FromImage()]

This is not entirely accurate, the red box does not match the text exactly. This should be expected though, because you are measuring *with* `StringFormat` flags and drawing *without*.

So to improve measurement, use the following line of code for drawing:

```
textImageGraphics.DrawString(text, font, Brushes.Black, New Point(0, 0), STRFormat)
```

Then the result looks like this, pretty accurate, on both OSes:

[image: Result with StringFormat flags]

On a side note, you can actually use `Me.CreateGraphics()` instead of `Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero)` when inside a `Control`. But it won't fix the problem here.

Does that help?

Comment: Sorry - I noted the error with the string format but cant correct the original post due to some account issues.  Ive done a bit more research in to the GDI+ methods but havent come up with an explanation. Good contender for bounty - will see in 3 days ;)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to not use

```
g = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero)
```

If it is replaced with this it works fine:

```
Dim resolution As Single = 96
Dim Im As New Bitmap(500, 100)
Im.SetResolution(resolution, resolution)
g = Graphics.FromImage(Im)
```

I do not understand why.  I've compared the graphics objects and cannot identify a difference that would explain it.

Bounty will go to the person that can tell me why.